Package keyval Error: scale=0.5 undefined
\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,svgnames,dvipsnames,table]{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{softset}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

I am attempting to create a presentation using Beamer, and I would like to insert an image into it. However, when I enter the standard code to do so, the 'scale' command is not functioning as expected, and I am receiving the error message displayed in the title. Is there anyone who could assist me in resolving this issue? Thank you in advance for your help.

If i change softset toexample-image (a generally available test image) then your code runs without error. Please show the full log from the example

There are errors of type as in the log: document.tex: error: 259: Package keyval Error: scale=0.5 undefined. \end{frame}
document.tex: bad box: 259: Overfull \hbox (720.54762pt too wide) in paragraph
document.tex: bad box: 259: Overfull \vbox (781.29088pt too high) detected

Probably unrelated, but did you maybe mean to use \documentclass[xcolor={svgnames,dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}?

No if that is an error on line 259 it is not an error generated from the code you posted. Show the full log from the posted code, preferably after changing the image to example-image

I thik you may be asking about the folloiwng: l.259 \end{frame}
Try typing    to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X   to quit.
<img.png, id=618, 1027.84pt x 1027.84pt>
File: img.png Graphic file (type png)

Package pdftex.def Info: img.png  used on input line 259.

@MBKandemir Please run the code as it is shown in your question and then copy the whole .log file you get into your question.

@MBKandemir as I say that error is from some document with at least 259 lines and including a file called img.png  so that file has an error but it is completely unrelated to the code that you posted, which does not have 259 lines and does not have an error. You need to post an example that generates the error you are asking about.

Do you per chance use an \includegraphics to which you pass a macro that contains your option (so something like \newcommand\myopts{scale=0.5}\includegraphics[\myopts]{softset}? That would also result in this error message.

The posted code produces no error (if you have the image file).
To get the error shown you need to "hide" the = so it is seen as part of the key name, not the separator before the value.

\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,svgnames,dvipsnames,table]{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[{scale=0.5} ]{example-image}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

produces
! Package keyval Error: scale=0.5 undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.13 \end{frame}
                
? 

